# Does exist a metric to evaluate "programming effort" between 2 different svn version of a java project?

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, netbeans-7, metrics

I'm upgrading a project (previously developed by another programmer) to a new version. The aim is to implement new features.
The project is written in Java, I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2 as IDE and Svn as versioning software.

Does exist a plugin or a software that analyze the original version and my last version of the project, giving some stats of my efforts? (For example difference in total number of code lines, total number of classes, etc etc)?

Comment: I mean, [`sloccount`](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) measures source lines of code, and you could just take the difference...?

Comment: There's a disconnect though since number of lines != effort.

Comment: Clearly.  But any automated "effort measurement" scheme will be crude at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/) is very good at that! I used it on my last Java project to see my team's effort (who is fixing lines of codes, who is adding new ones and such)